How to run Restful API with mvn clean install in IntelliJ Community Edition . The tomcat won't start
I am a newer on IntelliJ. I have a Spring Boot with Restful API. It works in Eclipse. But it won't start the Tomcat after I switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ. But it works if I right clicked on Application class and "Run Application main()...".
I used "mvn clean install" same as I did in Eclipse. it worked in Eclipse. But not in IntelliJ.

Please share more details about any error you encountered, in case it helps, check this thread: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/8139016146834/comments/8148609030418
